# Applying dyadic function on pairs from two lists

Tags: kdb

Suppose I have a dyadic function `f[x;y]`, and two lists

```
l1: a1 a2 a3 ...
l2: b1 b2 b3 ...
```

In KDB, how can I get

```
f[a1;b1] f[a2;b2] f[a3;b3] ...
```

?

Comment: Try each. https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each

Comment: I tried to apply the function cor to two lists of lists, but got a type error. For example, (1 2 3; 2 3 4) (cor') (1 2 3; 2 3 4) throws a type error. Could you please let me know why this fails?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `'` form of each.

```
q)l1:`a1`a2`a3
q)l2:`b1`b2`b3
q)f:{(x;y)}
q)f'[l1;l2]
a1 b1
a2 b2
a3 b3
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each

Comment: For a binary function `f` infix syntax is preferred for `f'`; that is `l1 f'l2`.